# Doctrine DQL join on nullable columns

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to join two tables based on a null-able column with the Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Using the default equality operator in Doctrine, translates into the regular equality operator in MySQL which returns `NULL` when comparing two `NULL` values.

I can achieve this in plain MySQL with the [null-safe operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.field, t2.field2
FROM table1 t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.field <=> t1.field)
```

However, as I presume `<=>` is MySQL specific, there is no out-of-the-box support for this in Doctrine?

Using the following query has been tried, but is unfortunately too resource intensive as this applies to quite some columns.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.field, t2.field2
FROM table1 t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON 
    (t2.field = t1.field AND t1.field IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (t2.field IS NULL AND t1.field IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 : Doctrine Native SQL

One way to achieve this is by using native MySQL queries.
This require the use of [Doctrine's Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class) feature and mapping the results of the query using a [ResultSetMapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-resultsetmapping).

I came across an issue when executing a Native SQL query twice (with different parameters), that the second query's result-set was the same as the first one.
[Following post on GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/255) solved this for me.

## Solution 2 : Using MySQL's internal optimizer

Using following join condition will use MySQL's internal optimizer and treat this as an [`ref_or_null`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_ref_or_null) join-type

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON 
       a.column = b.column 
       OR (a.column IS NULL AND b.column IS NULL)
```

It is then possible to use this join-condition in DQL, which will be translated nicely in SQL to be optimized.

## Solution 3 : Write Custom DQL function

I wrote a custom DQL-function that translated in the following clause:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON (a.column <=> b.column) = 1
```

Unfortunately is was not able to get rid of the `= 1` part of this clause. This worked, but caused a *major* performance impact on my query: 17s vs 0.5s, to give some (non-scientific) indication.
So i didn't go further down that road.

Comment: Many thanks for your work, I go for the solution 2 :)